# How to read Bar Coded Boarding Pass

Tags: barcode, zxing

I have a project in mind, and it requires that I read the barcode on the boarding pass, and figure out where the passenger is heading. (destination)

Is such thing possible? Is there any library (C++, Java, language doesn't matter at all) or maybe webservices that I can use to quickly read a bar code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can get the following information from the barcoded boarding pass: Name, Booking Ref., Flying from and to, Flight #, Date, etc.
So, you could figure out where the passenger is heading.

About the library perhaps you could take a look this [link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), a multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library with clients for Android, Java.

If you want to decode the barcode online, perhaps the following links could help:
1. http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx
2. search for datasymbol and barcode recognition sdk, there should be an online barcode decoder. Sorry, the system prevented me from posting another link.

Answer (score 1):

According to [BCBP Implementation Guide of International Air Transport Association](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/stb/documents/bcbp_implementation_guidev4_jun2009.pdf) you should be able to get those information from 4 different symbologies, in other words, in 4 different types of codes. The symbologies are divided by paper and mobile boarding pass.

- Paper: PDF417
- Mobile phones: Aztec code, Datamatrix and QR code

It is possible to get those information using libraries. The most popular library for decoding and encoding is [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) ("Zebra Crossing") project. You can decode all the mentioned codes through this library.

Besides I suggest you reading this [article](http://shaun.net/posts/whats-contained-in-a-boarding-pass-barcode) about boarding pass barcode contents and, of course, the official implementation guide.

Comment: Here's the updated version: https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/stb/Documents/BCBP-Implementation-Guide-5th-Edition-June-2016.pdf

Comment: all of the links (except for ZXing git) are broken